# Spring Mocking JWT authentication in Controller tests

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, jwt, mocking

I'm trying to unit test controller and I cannot mock JWT authentication - I've tried multiple approaches to mocking it, however nothing works. JWT tokens are generated by external SSO. Not sure if it's relevant, but application uses Activiti library. This is my current code:

Controller:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/my-controller")
public class MyControllerController {

    ...

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('admin', 'student','graduate')")
    @PostMapping(value = "", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ProcessStartedDTO> repeatingRequest(@CurrentUser UserDetails userDetails,
                                                              @RequestParam(value = "taskId", required = false) String taskId,
                                                              MyControllerRequest myControllerRequest) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Test:

```
@WebMvcTest(MyControllerController.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration
public class ScholarshipDisabledControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private SomeRequiredBean someRequiredBean;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(roles = {"student"})
    public void testCreatesNewProcessWhenNoTaskIdProvided() throws Exception {
        Jwt tjwt = Jwt.withTokenValue("token")
                .header("alg", "none")
                .claim("sub", "user")
                .claim("scope", "reuired-permision-backend-api.write")
                .build();

        ResultActions x = mockMvc.perform(
                multipart("/api/my-controller")
                        .param("test", "test")
                        //.header("Authorization", "Bearer ")
                        .with(jwt().jwt(tjwt).authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("student"), new SimpleGrantedAuthority("Student.Read"))))
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print());
    }

}
```

Result:

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Cache-Control:"no-store", Pragma:"no-cache", WWW-Authenticate:"Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="unauthorized", error_description="Full authentication is required to access this resource"", Content-Type:"application/xml;charset=UTF-8", X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"1; mode=block", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = application/xml;charset=UTF-8
             Body = <UnauthorizedException><error>unauthorized</error><error_description>Full authentication is required to access this resource</error_description></UnauthorizedException>
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```